# access javascript value in JSP hidden tag

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, jstl

I have a ajax call that returns me a JSON object, data.
Ajax and JSP code below

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        //AJAX Start            
        $.ajax({  
         type: "GET", 
         contentType : "application/json",
         url: "getInfo.do",  
         data: "&pNum=" + pNum,
         dataType : 'json',
         async: false,
        success: function(data){        
        if(data != null)
            alert(data.pTaxId);
            document.getElementById("pTaxId").value = data.pTaxId;
        else{
                resetFields();              
            }
        },  
         error: function(e){                    
            alert("Error..."+JSON.stringify(e)); 
         } 
        });


</script>       


<form:form action="addSubmit.do" commandName="pTax">
    <c:set var="pageNo" value="0" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="pTaxId" value="" />
    <form:hidden path="pTaxId" value=""/>
////
...
///
</form:form>
```

pTax is a POJO with pTaxId field. Tried setting the value for pTaxId in javascript like above in both input and form hidden but i am getting null value.
but alert(data.pTaxId) gives me a value like '5268'...any suggestion please?

Accessing value from java code as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/addSubmit.do")   
    public String addSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("pTax") PerTax perTax, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println("Value of pTaxId ::: "+perTax.getPTaxId()+":::");
        ////
        ...///
        }
```

Output: Value of pTaxId ::::::

Comment: It seems you have  "pTaxId" in ID and in `path`? What does the rendered HTML look like

Comment: @ mplungjan tried both to see if it works. But none worked.